# Xamarin Datapicker how customize it to be an calender image

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm new to Xamarin and I would like to know how can I set the DatePicker to be an image for example a calender instead of being text with a line under it (default).

The goal is to have an entry and next to it a calender image to have it's behaviour like a DatePicker like in the image below:

[image]

I have the following code but i have DatePicker commented. I tried to set isVisible = 'false' and have the image on it's position but it didn't work.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="360" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
         </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <Frame Style="{StaticResource FrameStyle}">
            <controls:CustomEntry x:Name="DataDocEntry" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat='{0:d/M/yy}', Source={x:Reference MainDatePicker}}" IsEnabled="false" Style="{StaticResource EntryStyle}" />
          </Frame>
          <!--<DatePicker x:Name="MainDatePicker" Grid.Column="1" MinimumDate="1/1/2018" MaximumDate="12/31/2030" HeightRequest="30" />-->
          <Image VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="End" Source="icalendar.png" HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="30">
            <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Calendario_Clicked" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
          </Image>
</Grid>
```

I also created a DatePickerRenderer to customize the DatePicker to try to set it's background as image but wasn't sucessful either.

**DatePickerRenderer.cs**

```
using Android.Content;
using FormsApp.Droid;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(DatePicker), typeof(MyRenderer))]
namespace FormsApp.Droid
{
    class MyRenderer : DatePickerRenderer
    {
        public MyRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {

        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<DatePicker> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                //Control.Background = "icalendar.png";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Best regards

Comment: Managed to do it with opacity = "0" !

Answer (score 1):

You could hide the DataPicker and use the Focus in the click event of image.

xaml:

```
  <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
        <Entry x:Name="entry" />
        <Image
            HeightRequest="20"
            HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
            Source="calendar.png"
            WidthRequest="20">
            <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped" />
            </Image.GestureRecognizers>
        </Image>
        <DatePicker
            x:Name="dataPicker"
            IsVisible="false"
            Unfocused="dataPicker_Unfocused" />
    </StackLayout>
```

Code behind:

```
  private void dataPicker_Unfocused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
    {
        entry.Text =dataPicker.Date.ToString();
    }

    private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataPicker.Focus();
    }
```

Comment: Hey i managed to do with:
<DatePicker x:Name="MainDatePicker" Grid.Column="1" MinimumDate="1/1/2018" MaximumDate="12/31/2030" HeightRequest="30" BackgroundColor="Gray" Opacity="0" />

And: 

   private void Calendario_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MainDatePicker.Focus();
        }

But thanks anyway